# Biblatex/biber - no citation, bibdata, or bibstyle found in .aux file

Tags: biblatex, compiling, biber, texniccenter

Yo peeps - sorry for the long post, trying to be thorough.

I'm having a bit of an issue with biblatex/biber.  I was having trouble implementing the `acro` package which I believed was due to old support files hanging out in the directory.  So I cleaned it out (FYI I'm using TeXnicCenter and I used the Build>Clean Project menu function).

Possibly a bad idea.  My file stopped compiling, complaining "Couldn't find input index file  or .idx" and "Couldn't open file name ".  So to try and fix it I just created 2 blank text files with .idx and .aux file extensions.  The problem then was that it complained that it couldn't find any \citation, \bibdata, and \bibstyle commands in the .aux file.

I then decided use LEd, it created the .idx and .aux files for me, and even puts some stuff in the .aux.  It was getting stuck trying to find the location of the images, so after commenting all out of the images (and references to their labels), it compiled.  But it still had the same original problem as TeXnicCenter where it couldn't find \citation, \bibdata, and \bibstyle commands.

My preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, bottom=3.5cm, top=3.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[
    font=footnotesize, 
    center
    ]{caption}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    natbib=true,
    maxnames=2,
    sorting=nyt,
    sortcites=false,
    block=space,
    date=long,
    url=false, 
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    isbn=false,
    uniquename=false,
    uniquelist=false,
    terseinits=true,
    firstinits=false
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../../BibTex/library.bib}

%Put initials after names...
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}    

%Remove "and" before last name. However, this also removes "and" in a textcite...
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[big,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=xxxx,
        pdfauthor=xxxx,
        pdfkeywords=xxxx
        }

\makeindex

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]                                 
\end{document}
```

I tried putting `\nocite{*}` in the preamble, but that didn't work.

I also wondered if it has something to do with `[backend=biber]{biblatex}` as I have read that this may put info in a .bcf file rather than the .aux file it expects.

Comment: Try to 1) put `\nocite{*}` after `\begin{document}`, and 2) move your file `library.bib` in the same folder and remove that path in `\addbibresource`.

Comment: If you use `backend=biber` and actually cite something in your test document (see above comment), running `latex` will produce a `.bcf` file, which is what `biber` needs.  The sequence, including extensions, is: `latex file.tex`, `biber file.bcf`, `latex file.tex`.  (Though normally you don't need to include the extensions.)  As for the index, I don't see you using any indexing commands --- shouldn't you get an empty `.idx` file?

Comment: Unfortunately it was an incredibly simple fix, spurred by @jon.  TeXnicCenter was calling the wrong compiler.  Doh!  Thanks for the help though.
@jon:  The only indexing command is `\makeindex` which I thought I was required to have to create contents, acronym lists, etc?  I take it that is nonsense?

Comment: @E_L -- No, you're right.  I just meant your example file above didn't have any commands in it that would generate any data for the `.idx`.  Anyway, I'm glad all's working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think I've managed to sort it.  Unfortunately it is embarrassingly simple.

I don't think TeXnicCenter was calling the right LaTeX compiler.  It was calling bibtex instead.  To remedy, go to the "Build" menu, select "Define Output Profiles...", then on the "LaTeX compiler" tab, make sure that the "Path to BibTex executable" is pointing to biber.exe.  And you need to make sure that the executable path is set for each of the profiles (PDF, DVI, PS, etc)

Can't believe I spent all weekend on this.

Comment: Or you copy the profile and adjust the new one!